# ActiveAndroid ORM: extension model ierarchy

Tags: android, activeandroid

I want to use activeAndroid lib, but for now I faced with difficulties - I have BaseMessage class and plenty of sublasses, I want to pack them into one table, but it seems it's impossible.
Pseudocode:

```
@Table(name = "BaseMessage")
public class BaseMessage extends Model{

@Column(name = "messageContentType")
public int messageContentType; 
...

public class MessagePhoto extends BaseMessage
```

I am using

```
BaseMessage.createMessage(...)
```

to create message of sertain type.
But when I add MessagePhoto type, it simply NOT put it into database.
Please show me the way to do it, or suggest any other ORM that can do such thing.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're writing to the db?

Comment: This may shed some light, I don't know: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/14

Comment: ActiveAndroid does not support inheritance. I just added all info from descendant classes to Base and used this class for all purposes